# How to activate Apple Storage

Tags: icloud, storage

I am paying for 50 GB of icloud storage. It shows up in my settings, but I can't access it. I am still deleting photos so I can store everything on the 5 GB I have. Have spent hours researching this but can only find others with the same problem. No answers from Apple.

Comment: So have you contacted apple support? If you're being billed for the storage it seems like a problem with their backend.

Comment: Also try signing out/in of your apple id

Answer (score -1):

I would logout of iCloud and log back in